# Layover at London Heathrow

Tags: uk, transit, layovers, indian-citizens, lhr

I am flying from Chicago(USA) to New Delhi(INDIA) via London Heathrow Airport(LHR). Actually the route is the following -

Chicago --> London Heathrow --> Munich --> New Delhi.

The layover at LHR and at Munich are of 2 hours each. I am worried if I need to get a transit visa for the flight to Munich. I have browsed through other questions related to this, but I just need an assuring confirmation that I won't need a transit visa.

Edit- I hold an Indian passport and study at the USA with F1 visa.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: I am an Indian citizen.

Comment: What did you learn from the other questions about this topic?

Comment: *I have browsed through other questions related to this* If they didn't help, be more specific about why not. Otherwise you risk getting this closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a Transit Visa in this case as your layover does not require you to get out of the airport. As long as you have a Valid US Visa and you are an Indian citizen anyway, you're good to go.

Also, just as the others posted. Check the links provided in the comments which should serve to answer your question completely regarding Transit Visa policy in UK and the Schengen Area.