# DATV visa application address

Tags: visas, usa, uk, paperwork, datv

I decided to apply for a DATV visa for my upcoming trip from SAN to LHR to 
Munich to LHR to Chennai, India. I have an Indian passport with a valid F1 and Schengen visa!
I looked at the UK website, and I can't find the address to which I have to post my application to. Will I be given a visa at the visa application center in San Diego?

Here is a link to the previous question I posted and my complete trip itinerary:
[Transit visa requirements for Multi-Leg flights through Heathrow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31127/9801)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should [apply online](https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa) (see [this page on the DATV](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa)). You will then need to have your fingerprints taken at the visa application center.

Comment: Yes i did apply and have my interview in Visa application center in San diego! Does that mean that i will be getting interviewed there and i will know my decision about my visa In San Diego?

Comment: @htnakum No, it means you will have your fingerprints taken there, you will be informed of the decision by email after which you will be sent your passport back. They will take your passport at the application center.

Comment: Oh ok! SO i need to make a return shipping label for them right? That's the only thing that's confusing me! Should i make a shipping label for them to return my passport or is it application center a place where i will undergo an interview (Like a typical embassy)

Comment: UPDATE: I took my biometrics in the VISA APPLICATION CENTER. They only require a photo ID and Appointment confirmation slip, Its enough to have US drivers license too. The Appointment confirmation slip was stamped with my passport number and the file number (??) , i Went there 30 minutes before my scheduled time for my 10 am appointment. I was called in at 10.30 am, They took my photo and finger prints and gave me a form with the address where i have to send my Application package(including passport) ..They didnt take the passport (This is done only in USA, Canada and Australia)

Comment: @htnakum I don't see the problem eitherway... You have an address to send your application to now...don't you?

Comment: UPDATE: 29th July 2014, It took 2 weeks for the embassy to issue your visa. I received an email on 14th July that my application package has been received and under scrutiny. I received my passport with a multi entry into heathrow for 6 months today. Thanks everyone! Hope the DATV application and procedure helps someone .